# Gesture Detector with a Custom View-Based Class

Tags: android, view, gesture

I hope you can help me figure out why the OnSwipe, OnDoubleTap, and onSingTapConfirmed methods defined in my CustomView class which is instantiated from an activity onCreate using the following line -

```
CustomView customView = new CustomView(this);
```

are not getting called.  The CustomView extends a View and implements MyGestureListener interface.  See code below.

```
public class CustomView extends View implements MyGestureListener {

private MyGestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    mGestureDetector = new MyGestureDetector(context, this);
}

@Override 
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){ 
    this.mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me); 
}

@Override
public void onSwipe(int direction) {
    String str = "";

    switch (direction) {

        case MyGestureDetector.SWIPE_RIGHT : 
              str = "Swipe Right";
              break;
        case MyGestureDetector.SWIPE_LEFT :  
              str = "Swipe Left";
              break;
        case MyGestureDetector.SWIPE_DOWN :  
              str = "Swipe Down";
              break;
        case MyGestureDetector.SWIPE_UP :    
              str = "Swipe Up";
              break;                                        
    } 

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDoubleTap() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
 }

 @Override
 public void onSingleTapConfirmed() {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Single Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
 }

}

public class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

 public final static int SWIPE_UP    = 1;
 public final static int SWIPE_DOWN  = 2;
 public final static int SWIPE_LEFT  = 3;
 public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

 public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
 public final static int MODE_SOLID       = 1;
 public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC     = 2;

 private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13;
 private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
 private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
 private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

 private int mode      = MODE_TRANSPARENT;
 private boolean running = true;
 private boolean tapIndicator = false;

 private Context context;
 private GestureDetector detector;
 private MyGestureListener listener;

 public MyGestureDetector(Context context, MyGestureListener sgl) {

  this.context = context;
  this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
  this.listener = sgl; 
 }


 public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

   if(!this.running)
       return;  

   boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event); 

   if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
       event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
   else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

     if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE) 
       event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
     else if (result)
       event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL); 
     else if(this.tapIndicator){
      event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
      this.tapIndicator = false;
     }

   }
   //else just do nothing, it's Transparent

 }


 public void setMode(int m){
  this.mode = m;
 }

 public int getMode(){
  return this.mode;
 }

 public void setEnabled(boolean status){
  this.running = status;
 }

 public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance){
  this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
 }

 public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance){
  this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
 }

 public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance){
  this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
 }

 public int getSwipeMaxDistance(){
  return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
 }

 public int getSwipeMinDistance(){
  return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
 }

 public int getSwipeMinVelocity(){
  return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
 }


 @Override
 public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
   float velocityY) {

  final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
  final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

  if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
   return false;

  velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
  velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        boolean result = false;

  if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
   if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
   else
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

   result = true;
  }
  else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
   if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up 
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
   else
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

   result = true;
  }

   return result;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
  this.tapIndicator = true;
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {
  this.listener.onDoubleTap();
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg0) {;
    this.listener.onSingleTapConfirmed();
    return true;
 }

 static interface MyGestureListener{
     void onSwipe(int direction);
     void onDoubleTap();
     void onSingleTapConfirmed();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return true in down action ... otherwise the other callbacks action will never be called ...as explained in [android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

> Beware of creating a listener that returns false for the ACTION_DOWN event. If you do this, the listener will not be called for the subsequent ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP string of events. This is because ACTION_DOWN is the starting point for all touch events.